# Trying to write a function that returns the number of digits in n that are divisble by m -- Too much output - Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function that will take `n` and `m` as an argument and then will return the number of digits in `n` that are divisible by `m`. An example of this could be n = 305689 and m = 3. The answer here would be 4.

My program is able to get this result, but the interface I'm working is is saying that my program is running for too long or producing too much output.

Here's my program so far:

```
def count_divisible_digits(n, m):
    count = 0
    while n != 0:
        if (n % 10) % m == 0:
            count += 1
        #print("dbg", count, n)
        n = n // 10
    return count
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: @ahmadjanan Fixed. Same issue

Comment: `print` produces the output.  If you have too much output, then you have to quit printing on every loop iteration.  Print only when you have something to report.

Comment: @Prune That's why I have `print` commented out. I was just using it to try and see if I had an infinite loop because someone suggested that. Still unsure of what to do though.

Comment: What are the constraints on `n`? Can it be negative?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, it can be negative. I don't believe the program I currently have is allowing it to be, but I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the input n to string datatype and getting the count as follows. This should be faster.

```
def count_divisible_digits(n, m):
  count = 0
  string = str(n)
  if n == 0 and m == 0:
    return 0
  elif m == 0:
    return 0
  elif n == 0: 
    return 1
  elif n < 0:
    x = 1
  else:
    x = 0
    
  for i in range(x, len(string)):
    if string[i] == '.' or 0 < int(string[i]) < m:
      continue
    elif int(string[i]) % m == 0:
      count += 1      
  return count
```

Comment: It's telling me that there's an `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-' ` on the fifth line

Comment: If it is working for positive numbers, then it can be made to work for negative numbers as well.

Comment: It worked for some testcases on the last one, this one doesn't work in general :/

Comment: When I try to pass negative numbers through it, that is where it's saying `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-' ` Do you know why this is?

Comment: You are getting this error because it was inputting a negative number to the function. I added a check for negative numbers. Try it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, same result as before

Comment: It would be easier if you posted all your test cases here.

Comment: `Correctly returns 0` (passed) `Passes (650899, 3)` (passed) `Passes (-204, 5)` (failed, `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'  `) `Returns 0 when given 0` (failed, `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` )

Comment: I’d suggest to check the data type of your input: type(n). Enter a negative number. Maybe it’s a string? If it is you’d need to convert it to int

Comment: I have added conditions for all the test cases. Try now. If you still get an error, paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this again, miss the `0` ✅ check now;

```
count =sum(1 for s in str(n) if int(s)%m==0 and int(s) >0)
```

Comment: What does this line do? It worked for a few different testcases, but not the normal ones like the example I provided.

Comment: My bad, put check for number greater than 0. Please check again. Thanks. (You can convert this to a function easier...)

Comment: Not sure I can understand?  Use string is simple and faster too.

Comment: Yeah, it's just part of the challenge I'm doing to not use a string. I just don't know how

Comment: OK. Will try later... No string.